# Dart: How can I add multiple attributes to a list object without getting an error?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's my code-

```
class TaskData extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Task> tasks = [
    Task(name: 'Doodh le', time: null, date: null),
    Task(name: 'Anda le', time: null, date: null),
  ];

  void addTask(String newTaskTitle, TimeOfDay newTime, DateTime newDate) {
    final task = Task(name: newTaskTitle);
    final deadlineTime = Task(time: newTime);
    final deadlineDate = Task(date: newDate);
    tasks.add(task, deadlineTime, deadlineDate); //err̥or
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I want to add all the data types (name, time, date) in a single Task list item. I'm unversed with the syntax.

Comment: You want to create multiple objects at once?

Comment: @Ashok No, I want to add all the data types (name, time, date) in a single Task list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add object of Task() in your list.
Your task class have three variable name, time and date.
Also, you have one constructor

```
Task({this.name, this.time, this.date});
```

Now if you want to add a new object in your list, you need to add Task object in it. You need to change you function like :-

```
void addTask(String newTaskTitle, TimeOfDay newTime, DateTime newDate) {
    final task = Task(name: newTaskTitle, time: newTime, date: newDate);
    tasks.add(task);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```